# Ruby thread mess up variable

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm new to ruby, and want to use thread. In purpose, I want thread to spawn thread, I have below code:

```
require 'thread'
semaphore = Mutex.new

thr = Array.new
outputs = Array.new
scripts = Array.new
for i in 1..3
  thr[i] = Thread.new do
      puts "adding #{i} thread\n"
      puts "ready to create #{i} thread\n"
      scripts[i]= Thread.new do
        puts "in #{i} thread\n"
        puts "X#{i}\n"
        outputs[i] = "a#{i}" 
      end
  end 
end
for i in 1..3
  thr[i].join
end
for i in 1..3
  scripts[i].join
end
for i in 1..3
  puts outputs[i]
end
```

The output is

```
adding 1 thread
adding 2 thread
adding 3 thread
ready to create 3 thread
ready to create 1 thread
ready to create 1 thread
in 1 thread
in 1 thread
in 2 thread
X2
X3
X1
C:/Users/user/workspace/ruby-test/test.rb:61: undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from C:/Users/liux14/workspace/ruby-test/test.rb:60:in `each'
    from C:/Users/liux14/workspace/ruby-test/test.rb:60
```

The first three lines are correct, but following i is messed up.

two i = 1 and one i = 2 and one i = 3. And the one of output[i] is nil.

What I missed?

Comment: You just saw your first race condition. Congrats. :)

Comment: Threads run concurrently.  You don't have any guarantees about what order things will happen in.  I would guess that your output will vary on repeated runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the `for i in 1..3` statement might be making `i` available outside of the for block, and makes it shared across the parent and child threads.

Try it with a block instead:

```
(1..3).each do |i|
  # code
end
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'thread'
semaphore = Mutex.new

thr = Array.new
outputs = Array.new
scripts = Array.new
(1..3).each do |i|
  thr[i] = Thread.new do
      puts "adding #{i} thread\n"
      puts "ready to create #{i} thread\n"
      scripts[i]= Thread.new do
        puts "in #{i} thread\n"
        puts "X#{i}\n"
        outputs[i] = "a#{i}" 
      end
  end 
end
(1..3).each do |i|
  thr[i].join
end
(1..3).each do |i|
  scripts[i].join
end
(1..3).each do |i|
  puts outputs[i]
end
```

---

```
denis@DB:~/wk $ ./test.rb 
adding 1 thread
ready to create 1 thread
adding 3 thread
ready to create 3 thread
adding 2 thread
ready to create 2 thread
in 1 thread
X1
in 3 thread
in 2 thread
X3
X2
a1
a2
a3
```

Comment: Thanks, but if it's shared, the second thr[2] get the value i=2, and reporting adding 2 thread, but why there are two i=1 thread? only the main thread is increasing i, so every time the main thread increase i by 1, the sub thread should never get i=1 twice, where am I wrong?

Comment: When you use the `for i in 1..3` construct instead of the iterator/each construct, `i` is not local to within each block. Instead, it's shared within the enclosing scope: the i in the thread-related `for` block gets overwritten (to 1 in your example) when the next `for` block kicks in.

Comment: Sorry, still a little confused, why it's overwritten to 1? Much appreciated

Comment: In your first for loop, i goes from 1 to 3 and starts three threads, all of which use (and share) `i`. The main thread continues on, alongside the child threads. Enter the next for loop from the main thread: the first thing it does is overwrite `i`, setting it to 1 in the parent thread ***and*** its three children. It contrast, the iterator approach I highlighted above ensures that `i` is local to each block.

Comment: Interesting, in my first loop, i goes from 1 to 3?? then the second loop, i is set to 1 and continue to 3 again? If this, the loop is 3x3=9 times?

Comment: Find this:http://web.archive.org/web/20120711111451/http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/the_evils_of_the_for_loop. I think explains, thank you so much!

Comment: You are talking about the second 'for' loop outside thr[i].join. i is not local with for loop as the article said, so i is written to 1 and makes thr[1].join. However the child thread may get delay and at this moment, i is set to 1 and I got all the mess.